# Procurar números no array multidimensional (várias camadas)

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de procurar um determinado número neste array ($arrayJobsAtivos):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [seg] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 1
                    [tarde] => 1
                )

            [ter] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 1
                    [tarde] => 1,2
                )

            [qua] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [qui] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [sex] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [seg] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [ter] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [qua] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [qui] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [sex] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [seg] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [ter] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [qua] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [qui] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

            [sex] => Array
                (
                    [manha] => 
                    [tarde] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Estou tentando desta maneira. Caso encontre, $jobUso é "verde". Caso não, "vermelho". Porém, acho que por ser multidimensional, não estou encontrando os valores, pois está caindo sempre no vermelho.

Uma coisa... se no index tiver mais de um número (ex: 1,2), também deve constar o verde... então, acredito que "in_array" não seja interessante, correto?

```
$jobUso = ((array_search(1, array_column($arrayJobsAtivos, 'manha')) !== false) || (array_search(1, array_column($arrayJobsAtivos, 'tarde')) !== false)) ? "verde" : "vermelho";
```

**EDIT**

Fiz desta maneira abaixo, e funciona. Porém, gostaria de saber se há uma opção mais curta e inteligente.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayJobsAtivos); $i++){

    // * Segundo nível - Dias da semana
    foreach($arrayJobsAtivos[$i] as $key => $value){

        // * Terceiro nível - Período do dia
        foreach($arrayJobsAtivos[$i][$key] as $periodo => $jobs){

            // * Explodimos a string porque pode haver mais de um job no período
            $jobsDoDia = explode(",",$jobs);

            // * Com isso, um array é gerado. Agora entramos num loop deste array para verificar se o ponteiro do array é igual ao do job vigente da lista
            for($j = 0; $j < count($jobsDoDia); $j++){

                if($jobsDoDia[$j] == 1){
                    $jobUso = "verde";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O `in_array` parece funcionar. Não entendi direito esse ultimo paragrafo.

Comment: @Francisco o que quis dizer é que, por exemplo, veja o index [0]['ter']['tarde']. Veja que ele tem a string "1,2". Se eu buscar com in_array procurando pelo item "1", ele não encontrará neste caso. Apenas trará o index [0]['seg']['manha'] e [0]['seg']['tarde'].